# xCode 9.4.1 no account with itunes connect access have been found for the team

Tags: ios, xcode9.4

[image: This is the error I am seeing]

I'm using Xcode 9.4.1

1. Clearning drived data.
2. Close full xcode and reopen.
3. Delete the certificate and add it again.
4. Delete account in deverlop team and add it again.
5. Delete account in xcode perferences and add it again.
6. I fixed the problem 2 days but failed all.

I'm test use Application Loader. But login fail. tried use password special
is fail password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the image you have shared, it seems that you only have access to developer account and not to iTunesConnect( renamed to AppStoreConnect by Apple). You should contact your admin to get the access for it.

> **Just a quick try:**
>
> Can you be able to login to this https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login
> with the credentials you are having? If not then you should contact your admin to grant you access. Otherwise there might be some other problem.

Try and share your results.

Comment: Thx. I managed to fix it by creating a new Apple ID and add it to iTunes Connect.  Set role developer.   can fix the problem.