# No accounts with AppStore connect access has been found for the team "XXX"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight

I am developing an App with react native and I want to make a Testflight using the Xcode. I am using Version 10.0 (10A255) of Xcode. I also added the distribute certificates to my keychain. My problem is that, at the end of a successful archivin, as soon as I want to validate my App, it shows me the following error:

> No accounts with AppStore connect access has been found for the team
>   "XXX"

What I did until now:

1- closing the Xcode and execute this: `rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

2- remove and add my Apple ID account

3- Restart everything from the scratch

4- I checked my App icon and they are fine

5- I have already logged in with the same Apple ID in iTunes and AppStore.

Non of the above measurements didn't help me to solve my problem. Could please help me?

Comment: Checkout if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055057/xcode-9-4-1-no-account-with-itunes-connect-access-have-been-found-for-the-team/52057572#52057572

Comment: @BhavinKansagara: thanks a lot.. it worked ..

Comment: Consider UpVoting that answer, to help others find it with ease, when face similar problem.

Answer (score 7):

Somehow Xcode disconnected from the keychain!

Just **close Xcode and reopen it**, open your project and archive/distribute, you'll see Xcode asking access to your keychain and then, it will work.